# Calling a 'dynamic' Object of a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I just came to the problem where I want to call a function of an Object inside a HashMap. I already searched it up and found one thread but sadly I don't understand it.

So here's my code

```
public class Seat {

  //some attributes

  public int getNumber() {
     return number;
  }
  public boolean isReserved() {
     return status;
  }
}

public class Hall {

  private HashMap mySeats;

  public HashMap getMeinePlaetze() {
      return meinePlaetze;
  }
  public void createSeats() {
      for (int i = 1; i <= this.getnumberOfSeats(); i++) {
        this.getMySeats().put(i, new Seat(i, 1));
      }
   }
}
public class Main {
  Hall h1 = new Hall(...);

  h1.createSeats();

  h1.getMySeats().get(2).isReserved();  //How do I have to write this to work out? 
}
```

I hope my intend is reasonable. Feel free to correct me if my code sucks. I already apologize for it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: private final Map<Integer, Seat> = new HashMap<>(); Why don't you do it this way?

Comment: And do not call getMySeats().put(...) to put a seat. It's a best practice to return unmodifiable Map when you call getMySeats(): return Collections.unmodifiableMap(mySeats).

Comment: You don't even need a Map, I think, an ArrayList would be enough in this case. private final List<Seat> mySeats = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: then you add a seat by mySeats.add(new Seat(...)); and return your List by: public List<Seat> getMySeats() { return Collections.unmodifiableList(mySeats); }

Comment: Generic Collections

Comment: @LowLevel
Hi, thanks for your answer. The thought behind a hashmap is the dynamic name of the seats. Since there is obviously more that one for each hall. In order to not create like 100 lines of code to create these object it tumbled over the hashmap. Would you please clarify your second comment. I don't really understand it.

Comment: @LowLevel Would you also please clarify how I call the methods of e.g. Seat1(Row=1,Number=4). Thanks in advance.

Comment: I would make the Seat class with those properties: `private int row` and `private int number`. I think, it's not a good practice to link a map-key or an array-index to one of those meaningful properties (row or number)..

Comment: Ok, I'll post my answer, otherwise it's difficult to explain the hole structure in comments.

Comment: I've posted my answer.

Comment: It doesn't mean you do it wrong or I do it right. I just want to show why you better not put a link between a meaningful property and an array index or map-key.

Comment: Especially when you start to put your seats into your database, problems begin to rise up.

Comment: Map is very useful, of course, but it has it's own domain of "best-choice" (for instance: a cumulative sum, custom error handling, and so on).

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarify. It helps me alot understanding it!

Comment: You're welcome :) I'm glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following my tip in the comments, I wouldn't use a Map to link a meaningful row or number to a map-key or an array-index.

So, actually I would do it this way (because you asked, what I mean with my tip):

**Seat:**

```
public class Seat {

    private final int row;
    private final int number;
    private boolean reserved = false;

    public Seat(int row, int number) {
        this.row = row;
        this.number = number;
    }

    public boolean reserve() {
        if (!reserved) {
            reserved = true;
            return reserved;
        }
        return !reserved;
    }

    public int getRow() {
        return row;
    }

    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }

    public boolean isReserved() {
        return reserved;
    }

    public boolean is(int row, int number) {
        return this.row == row && this.number == number;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 23 * hash + this.row;
        hash = 23 * hash + this.number;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Seat other = (Seat) obj;
        if (this.row != other.row) {
            return false;
        }
        return number == other.number;
    }
}
```

---

**Hall:**

```
public class Hall {

    public final Set<Seat> seats = new HashSet<>();

    public Set<Seat> getSeats() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableSet(seats);
    }

    public void createSeats(int lastRow, int seatsPerRow) { // This is an example; in case you have different count of seats per row, you better make an boolean addSeat(int row, int number) function; boolean to check if it has been added or if the seat already exists
        for (int row = 1; row <= lastRow; row++) {
            for (int number = 1; number <= seatsPerRow; number++) {
                seats.add(new Seat(row, number));
            }
        }
    }

    public Seat get(int row, int number) {
        for (Seat seat : seats) { // or you use seats.iterator; I personally hate Iterators; it is my subjective point of view.
            if (seat.is(row, number)) {
                return seat;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean reserve(int row, int number) {
        Seat seat = get(row, number);
        if (seat != null) {
            return seat.reserve();
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

---

**And my Test-drive:**

```
public class TestDrive {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Hall hall = new Hall();
        int lastRow = 15;
        int seatsPerRow = 10;
        hall.createSeats(lastRow, seatsPerRow);

        boolean reserved = hall.reserve(5, 9);
        System.out.println("Seat(Row=5, Number=9) is reserved: " + (reserved == hall.get(5, 9).isReserved()));

        boolean reservedAgain = hall.reserve(5, 9);
        System.out.println("Seat(Row=5, Number=9) cannot be reserved again: " + (reservedAgain != hall.get(5, 9).isReserved()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since version 5, Java has a feature called *Generics*. You'll find a lot about generics on the web, from articles, blog posts, etc to very good answers here on StackOverflow.

Generics allows Java to be a *strongly typed* language. This means that variables in Java can not only be declared to be of some type (i.e. `HashMap`), but also to be of some type along with one or more *generic type parameters* (i.e. `HashMap<K, V>`, where `K` represents the type parameter of the keys of the map and `V` represents the type parameter of the values of the map).

In your example, you are using a raw `HashMap` (raw types are types that allow for generic type parameters to be specified, however the developer has not specified them). Raw types are considered bad practice and are highly error-prone, as you are experiencing right now.

`HashMap` allows two generic type parameters (one for the keys and another one for the values). In your case, you are using `Integer` for the keys and `Seat` for the values. Put into simple words, you are mapping integers to seats, or you can also say that your map is a map of integers to seats.

So, inside you `Hall` class, you should define your map with its generic type parameters:

```
private Map<Integer, Seat> mySeats = new HashMap<>();
```

Then, this code:

```
h1.getMySeats().get(2)
```

will return an instance of type `Seat`, because your map already knows that all its values are of type `Seat`.

So your code:

```
h1.getMySeats().get(2).isReserved();
```

will compile fine and will work without any errors.

Please note that, apart from declaring the generic types of your map, I've also changed two additional things.

First, I've created an actual instance of `HashMap` by using its constructor:

```
mySeats = new HashMap<>()
```

If you don't create an instance of your type with `new`, there won't be any `HashMap` instance where to put your seats later, and you'll get a `NullpointerException` (try it!).

Secondly, I've changed the type of the variable from `HashMap` to `Map`. `HashMap` is a class, while `Map` is just an interface. The thing is that the `HashMap` class implements the `Map` interface, so, unless your code explicitly needs to access a method of `HashMap` that is not declared in the `Map` interface (which is almost never the case), you will be fine with the `mySeats` variable being of type `Map<Integer, Seat>` instead of `HashMap<Integer, Seat>`. This is called *programming to the interface* and is a best practice that you should embrace from the very beginning. It will save you a lot of headaches in the future.

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation. It made me understand it better.

Answer (score 1):

```
h1.getMySeats().get(2).isReserved();
```

Please use an IDE like IntelliJ IDEA. It will tell you about mistakes like forgetting parentheses while typing.